# Scrapy - removing html tags in a list output

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to write a small script that will extract steam game tags and store them in a csv file. The issue I'm having currently is that I do not know how to remove the html tags from my output. My code is below

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import scrapy
from Example.items import SteamItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class SteamSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'steamspider'
    allowed_domains = ['https://store.steampowered.com/app']
    start_urls = ["https://store.steampowered.com/app/578080/PLAYERUNKNOWNS_BATTLEGROUNDS/",]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    tags = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="game_highlights"]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]')
    for sel in tags:
        item = SteamItem()
        item['gametags'] = sel.xpath('.//a/text()').extract()
        item['gametitle'] = sel.xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/text()').extract()
    yield item
```

My Item class:

```
class SteamItem(scrapy.Item):
    #defining item fields
    url = scrapy.Field()
    gametitle = scrapy.Field()
    gametags = scrapy.Field()
```

My output then looks like this:

```
[u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSurvival\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tShooter\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMultiplayer\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPvP\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tThird-Person Shooter\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFPS\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAction\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBattle Royale\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOnline Co-Op\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTactical\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCo-op\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEarly Access\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFirst-Person\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tViolent\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tStrategy\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tThird Person\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCompetitive\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTeam-Based\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDifficult\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSimulation\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'],
```

My objective is to remove all the tags "u'\r\n\t.....\t

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you are using Scrapy framework, you can use a library that comes with Scrapy called w3lib

```
import w3lib.html
output= w3lib.html.remove_tags(input)
print(output)
```

**scrapy.utils.markup is depreciated in 2019 and please use w3lib instead.**

You can refer to https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html for more info.

Comment: The `w3lib.html` remove only the html tags, in case of ```\r\n\t\t\```. I used the `.replace('\r\n\t\t\', '')`

Answer (score 3):

Simply Use `remove_tags`

```
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
ToRemove = remove_tags(YourOutPut)
print(ToRemove)
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: It's not recommended anymore:
WARNING: <string>:1: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.utils.markup` is deprecated. Please import from `w3lib.html` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To get the title and tags accordingly, you can try the following script. To get rid of tabs and whitespaces you should use `.strip()` on `.extract_first()`.

```
import scrapy

class SteamSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'steamspider'
    start_urls = ["https://store.steampowered.com/app/578080/PLAYERUNKNOWNS_BATTLEGROUNDS/",]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//*[@class='apphub_AppName']/text()").extract_first().strip()
        tag_name = [item.strip() for item in response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"popular_tags")]/*[@class="app_tag"]/text()').extract()]
        yield {"title":title,"tagname":tag_name}
```

Comment: On new code, `.get()` can be a more pythonic alternative to `.extract_first()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that what you're trying to remove is not "HTML tags", but simply whitespace, most of which in your case are tab characters, with a few newlines thrown in.  You might want to re-title you question to better express this.

As far as stripping the whitespace, the HTML library you're using might provide a function for this.

If it doesn't, or in the more general case of this problem, Python strings have a `strip` method (and some relations) that will return the string with all leading and trailing whitespace removed.  Thus, you could do something like :

```py
item['field'] = sel.xpath('...').extract().strip()
```

More info available in the Python manual: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Comment: .extract() returns a list, you can't apply strip() to a list

Answer (score 0):

```
item['gametags'] = sel.xpath('.//a/text()').extract()
item['gametitle'] = .xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/text()').extract()
```

`strip` your values while extracting as :

```
item['gametags'] = [val.strip() for val in sel.xpath('.//a/text()').extract()]
```

Same apply for your second extractor :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip` method. Since you are using `extract()` which will eventually return a list, you can try this.

```
item['gametags'] = list(map(str.strip, sel.xpath('.//a/text()').extract())
item['gametitle'] = list(map(str.strip, sel.xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/text()').extract())
```

You can also follow [this blog article](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/07/07/scraping-the-steam-game-store-with-scrapy) for steam scraping

Answer (score 0):

Using `strip()` is one way to do it. However, if you would like to achieve this entirely using XPath, take a look at [normalize-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function. In your case just change extraction of the values to:

```
item['gametags'] = [a.xpath('normalize-space(.)').extract_first() for a in sel.xpath('.//a')]
item['gametitle'] = sel.xpath('normalize-space(//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3])').extract_first()
```